# StackApps API is down.

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

It seems to not be responding to any request.

** at least according to [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/api.stackapps.com)*

**Update:** seems like *all* the SE sites are down :(

Comment: It's up now. **BUT** the link in my post still says it's down... weird.

Comment: **Now it's down again!** I better stop posting here before this becomes a long conversation with myself :)

Comment: eh.  It's like twitter, it's up or it's down.

Who cares, it's still in beta

Comment: @Matt: **twitter is in beta!?!** Just kidding, but your sentence is worded poorly :)

Comment: @george is being a grammar nazi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is back up, we experienced some hardware related issues.

Comment: Perfectly understandable. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

George, the api is not down even though downforeveryone says it is.

I am not sure what downforeveryone is checking, but you might want to check

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users?filter=mike&sort=name&pagesize=0&page=0

http://api.stackapps.com/0.9/users?filter=mike&sort=name&pagesize=0&page=0

so, even now, up to an hour later, downforeveryone still reports down when it isn't.

this is the first time i have heard of downforeveryone and i am not impressed.

Comment: Ya, me neither - I discovered the same thing you did - it's innaccurate.